# Double ng-repeate and ng-src bound to a function

Tags: angularjs, function, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make a grid of squares and fill it dynamically with images. What I have is an array with objects like this one:

```
{
  img: "./images/1.jpg",
  x: 1,
  y: 1
}
```

The x and y coordinates will represent the squares on the grid.

**partial.hmtl**

```
<div ng-repeat="row in squaresCtrl.getGridSize()  track by $index">
   <div ng-repeat="col in squaresCtrl.getGridSize() track by $index">
        <div id="{{row +','+col}}" class="square">
              <img ng-src="{{squaresCtrl.getSquare(row,col)}}">
        </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**app.js**

```
self.getSquare = function (row, col) {
            self.clickedSet.squares.forEach(function (sq) {
                if (sq.x === row && sq.y === col) {
                    console.log("x:"+row);
                    console.log("y:"+col)
                    console.log(sq.img);
                    return sq.img;
                }
            });
        };
```

The id of the div is set as expected, but then I don't get any images loaded. When I print the result of the function, it seems to be called many times. I am new to Angular and I am sure I am missing something major about how the function is executed in the ng-repeat.

**EDIT**
Here is a picture of the first two div rendered in the browser. There is an image tag, but without any attributes.

[image]

I have 25 objects. And from the `console.log` I get printed the first 5(1,1; 1,2; 1,3; 1,4; 1,5) and then 3 times the whole list of 25 objects.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: On the face of it I can't see any issues. If you inspect the element using browser Developer Tools, can you see if any `<img>` tag is even rendered on the page? If it is, can you [edit] the question to show the complete tag?

Comment: Using functions in a ngRepeat like you did is a bad idea. Those function's will get called over and over again. That will kill performance. (also the changes are real that it will error out).
If you make a plunk with your problem, I can help you out, and fix it for you.